# Xcode warning : no rule to Process file when build phases has this file?

Tags: ios, xcode, architecture

Check dependencies

warning: no rule to process file '/Users/priyankgandhi/Desktop/priyank/WalkUpAlarmRailways/Reachability.h' of type sourcecode.c.h for architecture i386

warning: no rule to process file '/Users/priyankgandhi/Desktop/priyank/WalkUpAlarmRailways/Reachability.h' of type sourcecode.c.h for architecture x86_64

How to solve it?

Comment: http://joytek.blogspot.tw/2011/09/xcode-4-warning-no-rule-to-process-file.html

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Follow these steps,

1. Select the project target
2. Select the Build Phases
3. Expand the Compile Source
4. Remove the Header file (Reachability.h)

note : for removing the Reachability.h file from Compile Source, first select the file and then press the - button

Hope this may help you

Comment: If you need the header, then make sure that it is added to the "Headers" list below "Compile Sources".

Answer (score 5):

Recently i was getting this issue , the main reason was i included .h files compile resources , which we shouldn't

so simple solution is

1. go to target , select build phases
2. search for .h files
3. delete all .h files under compile resources .